# Check for a string in a line in a file if the line contains a sentence

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have requirement to check for "IF EXISTS" clause present in the line if the line contains "DROP TABLE" statment.

```
grep "DROP TABLE" *
```

above statement gives all the lines in all the files in directory having DROP TABLE statement. But it will not give if there are multiple spaces between DROP and TABLE. I want a command to fetch only those lines that have DROP table statement but not IF EXITS clause ignoring multiple spaces in between

```
DROP TABLE TABLE1  IF EXISTS;
## command should not display above line

DROP    TABLE TABLE1  IF    EXISTS;
## command should not display above line

DROP TABLE TABLE1  ;
### command should display above line

DROP      TABLE table1;
### command should display above line
```

Appreciate response :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `grep` uses basic regular expressions. You can express your criteria like this:

```
grep "DROP \+TABLE" * | grep -v "IF \+EXISTS"
```

The `-v` inverts the match.

Using the `-v` "[word regex](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control)" mode would perhaps be safer (but a proper parser would be best if your input file could contain arbitrarily complex SQL statements):

```
grep -w "DROP \+TABLE" * | grep -vw "IF \+EXISTS"
```

If your file contained a line like:

```
NODROP TABLE FOO
```

The first version would include it in the output but the second wouldn't.

```
DROP TABLE FOO IF ISEXISTSWHATERVER
```

Would be included by the first version but filtered out by the one with the `-w`.

Thanks to [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) for the `-w` suggestion.

Comment: I would use `grep -w` and `grep -vw`

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl, included something about that. I don't often remember that very useful match mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '/\yDROP[[:blank:]]+TABLE\y/ && !/\yIF[[:blank:]]+EXISTS\y/' file
```

Explanation:

Basically the command looks like this:

```
awk '/DROP TABLE/ && !/IF EXISTS/' file
```

which prints lines with DROP TABLE in it but which do not contain IF EXISTS.

Then we allow multiple spaces or tabs in between

```
awk '/DROP[[:blank:]]+TABLE/ && !/IF[[:blank:]]+EXISTS/' file
```

At the end we align them on *word boundaries* to make sure `DROP` wouldn't match somethink like `XYDROP`

```
awk '/\yDROP[[:blank:]]+TABLE\y/ && !/\yIF[[:blank:]]+EXISTS\y/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try tr -s ''. This would remove multiple spaces in between

```
echo "DROP    TABLE" | tr -s ' ' | grep "DROP TABLE"
```

Comment: this will trim out the extra space. However it does not solve my requirement. Any thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports  Perl regex (most likely):

```
grep -P 'DROP\s+TABLE\s+\w+\s*(?!IF\s+EXISTS)\s*;' *
```

Check the [**explantion**](https://regex101.com/r/Exarrf/1)